# PerformClick does not work properly

Tags: android, button, onclick, dialog

I am trying to make a dialog like a tooltip using EasyDialog.

When I show this dialog open with clicking button, everything works fine.

But the problem is when I want to show this dialog at when the activity starts

I tried to show dialog by using button.performClick(). I put toast to make sure that the onClickListener is called. The result was that, The toast is showed normally but the dialog  does not.

When I debug the program, I see that these lines of code are executing but I can't understand why the dialog does not display.

Note that the library I use to show the dialog is [Here](https://github.com/michaelye/EasyDialog).

Here is the code :

```
    btnBottomLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBottomLeft);
    btnBottomLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new EasyDialog(MainActivity.this)
                    .setLayoutResourceId(R.layout.layout_tip_image_text)
                    .setBackgroundColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color_yellow))
                    .setLocationByAttachedView(btnBottomRight)
                    .setGravity(EasyDialog.GRAVITY_TOP)
                    .setAnimationTranslationShow(EasyDialog.DIRECTION_X, 300, 400, 0)
                    .setAnimationTranslationShow(EasyDialog.DIRECTION_Y, 300, 400, 0)
                    .setAnimationTranslationDismiss(EasyDialog.DIRECTION_X, 300, 0, 400)
                    .setAnimationTranslationDismiss(EasyDialog.DIRECTION_Y, 300, 0, 400)
                    .setTouchOutsideDismiss(true)
                    .setMatchParent(true)
                    .setMarginLeftAndRight(24, 24)
                    .setOutsideColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.outside_color_trans))
                    .show();
        }
    });
    btnBottomLeft.performClick();
```

So, problem is that, the dialog opens correctly by clicking button.

but `btnBottomLeft.performClick()` just show the toast, not the dialog.

What should I do to make dialog open?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: where do you call `btnBottomLeft.performClick();`? In the onCreate method of an Activity?

Comment: yes, in onCreate method @donfuxx

Comment: Maybe try to perform the click at a later stage, like for example in onResume and see if anything changes.

Comment: Again, I have this problem @donfuxx